# Add objects from one array to another in javascript with different structure

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say I have this array:

```
var smallCountries =[
{
    'id': 'background',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': 'source1',
    'layout': {
        'visibility': 'visible'
    }
}, {
    'id': 'SmallCountriesBorders',
    'source': 'composite',
    'source-layer': 'smallCountries-6ictci',
    'type': 'line',
    'minzoom': 0,
    'maxzoom': 2,
    'layout': {
        'line-join': 'bevel'
    }
}
];
```

and this other array:

```
var totalCountries = [

{
    'id': 'water',
    'source': 'mapbox-streets',
    'source-layer': 'water',
    'type': 'fill',
    'paint': {
        'fill-color': '#D0D7DA'
    }
}, {
    'id': 'background',
    'type': 'background',
    'paint': {
        'background-color': '#D0D7DA',
        'background-opacity': 1,
    }
}
];
```

and I want to include the objects of `smallCountries` in the `totalCountries` array, for now what I did was:

```
var totalCountries = [
...,
smallCountries[0],
smallCountries[1]
];
```

and it works but it is not a long term solution because `smallCountries` will be dynamically fill and not always will have all the properties.

Comment: you could use concat or splice with spread syntax.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat  ?

Comment: You mean `totalCountries.concat(smallCountries)` or `for (var i=0;i<smallCountries.length;i++) totalCountries.push(smallCountries[i])`?